# Heroku custom domain rewritten to herokuapp URL

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, dns

I've been trying to point a custom domain (let's say `www.example.com`) to my app: `my-app.herokuapp.com`.

I have read the heroku tutorial about setting up a custom domain by setting CNAME www to `my-app`. I have also added the custom domain via `heroku domains:add www.example.com`.

This works, but not as I wanted: when I type www.example.com in my browser, the URL **changes** to `my-app.herokuapp.com`.

**What should I do so that when users type in www.example.com, their URL is not rewritten to `my-app.herokuapp.com`  ?**
(Eg. `www.example.com/browse` should be equivalent to `my-app.herokuapp.com/browse`)

When I ran `curl -I www.example.com` it returns 302 response code (moved permanently) .

**Note: I don't have access to the custom domain, so I just want to make sure that I've done everything I could from my side.**

Thanks!

Comment: that sounds like you've setup domain forwarding and not a CNAME entry - perhaps there's a setting for your domain that has enabled forwarding somewhere?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought also, but I don't have access for the custom domain; I have to wait for my colleague to respond. Apart from DNS misconfiguration, is it possible that some misconfiguration from the application side (e.g. routing, controllers) can cause this to happen?(I doubt it though, since I didn't do anything out of the ordinary.)

Comment: unlikely although it is possible if you're using some kind of redirection within the application itself to the .herokuapp.com name.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Well, im not using any settings; just plain, vanilla Rails although i do have an assets precompile setting (but im pretty sure that wont affect anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specificly related to this: [cPanel CNAME record is being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706159/cpanel-cname-record-is-being-ignored)

Bottom line is, the provider somehow blocked any DNS configurations made by clients via cPanel.

The only allowed configuration was only redirect (302), so when I removed the redirection rule, it instead searches for `index.html` / `index.php` in my public folder (ignoring the CNAME records).

I solved this by directly contacting my domain provider's tech support to make the necessary changes.