# cPanel CNAME record is being ignored

Tags: dns, cpanel, cname

I'm using cPanel version 11.42.0 (build 23).

As the title suggests, I'm having problem trying to point my domain to a heroku app by setting a CNAME: `www.my-site.com. 14400 IN CNAME something.herokuapp.com`

I've also removed the A record of my root domain,
`my-site.com. 14400 IN A x.x.x.x` (server IP address)
I've waited for more than 4 hours, but the CNAME is still not propagated.
When I ran a DNS lookup for `www.my-site.com` (via http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx), it says that no CNAME record exist. Instead, **there's an A record for `www.my-site.com` pointing to `x.x.x.x`** (this record **does not exist** in my cPanel's Advanced DNS Zone Editor).

I also ran a DNS lookup for `my-site.com`, and it says that there's an A record for it pointing to `x.x.x.x` (Even though **I've deleted the record**?)

It's as if there's another zone file that "overrides" my cPanel zone file.

Here is my current DNS configuration (in advanced dns zone editor):

```
localhost.my-site.com.  14400   IN  A   127.0.0.1
mail.my-site.com.   14400   IN  CNAME   x.x.x.x 
ftp.my-site.com.    14400   IN  A   x.x.x.x 
cpanel.my-site.com. 14400   IN  A   x.x.x.x 
webdisk.my-site.com.    14400   IN  A   x.x.x.x 
whm.my-site.com.    14400   IN  A   x.x.x.x 
webmail.my-site.com.    14400   IN  A   x.x.x.x 
autoconfig.my-site.com. 14400   IN  A   x.x.x.x 
autodiscover.my-site.com.   14400   IN  A   x.x.x.x
www.my-site.com.    14400   IN  CNAME   something.herokuapp.com
```

What should I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the domain provider somehow "blocked" any changes made by clients in the cPanel.

I solved this by directly contacting their tech support to make the necessary changes.